# How to retrieve the child data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks as follows, in here I want to retrieve the data inside the `mylocation` child (see the attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY76O.jpg)). But it is not working.
How to solve that?

My current code looks as this,

```
private void loadAddress() {
        DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(firebaseAuth.getUid())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String name=""+ds.child("name").getValue();

                            String lat=""+ds.child("name2").getValue();

                             addresstv.setText(name);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data under `mylocation`, you use an explicit call to that child, like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("name2").getValue(String.class);
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", name + "/" + latitude + "/" + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
5555/79.8571577/6.9448882
```